# Spread operator on NextJS 12 React Element is broken

Tags: next.js

I have reproduced an odd error down to the spread operator causing some problems with my nextjs app after recent updates. It works fine when doing `npm build` but when using dev mode i am experiencing the following:

I have a render function for layouting that looks like the following:

```
function xx(){

    return (
        <RootLayout {...{ hello:"world" }} key="AppLayout" id="AppLayoutId">
            <Layout id="PageLayout" key="PageLayout" title={appInfo.title}>
                <Component   app={app} key="PageComponent" id="PageComponentId" />
            </Layout>
        </RootLayout>
    )
}
```

and it works when not using the `{...{ hello:"world" }}` spread operator. I added a console.log to RootLayout where when the spread operator is used i get

[image]

and without spread operator

[image]

I also noticed how the output is different when using spread or not

```
 return (/*#__PURE__*/
    (0,
    react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV)(RootLayout, {
        id: "AppLayoutId",
        children: /*#__PURE__*/
        (0,
        react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV)(Layout, {
            id: "PageLayout",
            title: appInfo.title,
            children: /*#__PURE__*/
            (0,
            react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV)(Component, {
                app: app,
                id: "PageComponentId"
            }, "PageComponent", false, {
                fileName: "C:\\dev\\kfst_vanddata\\apps\\KFST.Vanddata.ManagementPortal\\src\\pages\\_app.tsx",
                lineNumber: 80,
                columnNumber: 17
            }, _this)
        }, "PageLayout", false, {
            fileName: "C:\\dev\\kfst_vanddata\\apps\\KFST.Vanddata.ManagementPortal\\src\\pages\\_app.tsx",
            lineNumber: 79,
            columnNumber: 13
        }, _this)
    }, "AppLayout", false, {
        fileName: "C:\\dev\\kfst_vanddata\\apps\\KFST.Vanddata.ManagementPortal\\src\\pages\\_app.tsx",
        lineNumber: 78,
        columnNumber: 9
    }, _this))
```

and with spread operator (notice hello world)

```
 return (/*#__PURE__*/
    (0,
    react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.createElement)(RootLayout, {
        hello: "world",
        key: "AppLayout",
        id: "AppLayoutId",
        __source: {
            fileName: "C:\\dev\\kfst_vanddata\\apps\\KFST.Vanddata.ManagementPortal\\src\\pages\\_app.tsx",
            lineNumber: 78,
            columnNumber: 9
        },
        __self: _this,
        children: /*#__PURE__*/
        (0,
        react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV)(Layout, {
            id: "PageLayout",
            title: appInfo.title,
            children: /*#__PURE__*/
            (0,
            react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV)(Component, {
                app: app,
                id: "PageComponentId"
            }, "PageComponent", false, {
                fileName: "C:\\dev\\kfst_vanddata\\apps\\KFST.Vanddata.ManagementPortal\\src\\pages\\_app.tsx",
                lineNumber: 80,
                columnNumber: 17
            }, _this)
        }, "PageLayout", false, {
            fileName: "C:\\dev\\kfst_vanddata\\apps\\KFST.Vanddata.ManagementPortal\\src\\pages\\_app.tsx",
            lineNumber: 79,
            columnNumber: 13
        }, _this)
    }, void 0, false, void 0, void 0));
};
```

Did something change with how spread and tsx elements work in recent NextJS (upgraded from 11 to 12)

Comment: Adding a babel file causes "[0] info  - Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled" which result in it working as old times

Comment: It might be a bug in the SWC compiler introduced in [Next.js 12](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12#faster-builds-and-fast-refresh-with-rust-compiler). Also potentially related: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/30174.